# C# Selenium GetElements get error data

Tags: c#, selenium

Sorry, my English is not good.

I use Selenium to get datas from web,
Here is my code

```
var workGroups = e.WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='workgroup']"));

                    Console.WriteLine($"Item List: {workGroups.Count} Items");

        foreach (var workgroup in workGroups)
        {
            string workName = workgroup.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='worktitle']/label")).Text;

            var detail = workgroup.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='col-4 high']"));

            Console.WriteLine($"Item Name: {workName}, Number of Pictures: {detail.Count}");
        }
```

And this is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMWVg.jpg)

It seems to be catching the first data and all pictures,
I use chromedriver to help me.

I don't know where it is wrong.
Please help me, brothers and sisters.
thank you very much.

Comment: which error/exception does it throw ?

Comment: No exceptions, but I caught 7 identical data.

Comment: Could you please provide HTML code? It seems like the issue is with the XPaths you are using and we cannot resolve it without the HTML data you are working on.

Comment: I can provide the website: http://www.henrychang.tw/Body/Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
string workName = workgroup.FindElement(By.XPath("./div[@class='worktitle']/label")).Text;
var detail = workgroup.FindElements(By.XPath("./div[@class='col-4 high']"));
```

I didn't test that but assuming from using `workgroup` element you would like to get only elements that are "inside" the `workgroup` element area. However, to do so you need to use current "folder" notation (`./`) instead of root element notation (`//`) which looking for elements starting from root node in your HTML document and actually going through the entire document.

Comment: or workgroup.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='worktitle']/label"))

Comment: So it is because I use root element notation.
I'll try, Thank you!